# Javascript difference between function.prototype.constuctor.name and function.name

Tags: javascript

In javascript what is the difference between function.prototype.constuctor.name  and function.name or is it the same function ?

```js
function print() {
  console.log('print')
}

console.log(print.name)
console.log(print.prototype.constructor.name)
```

Comment: `print.prototype.constructor === print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. `print.prototype.constructor` is just a reference back to `print`, the exact same function. This is so that if you were to use the function as a constructor, the resulting instance would have a reference back to its constructor through the prototype chain.

```js
function print() {
  console.log('print')
}

let p = new print();
console.log(p.constructor);
```